# concatenating selected elements in a list of lists in python

Tags: python, list

I have a `(python) list of lists` as below

```
biglist=[ ['1','123-456','hello','there'],['2','987-456','program'],['1','123-456','list','of','lists'] ]
```

I need to get this in the following format

```
biglist_modified=[ ['1','123-456','hello there'],['2','987-456','program'],['1','123-456','list of lists'] ]
```

I need to concatenate the `third element onwards` in each inner list.I tried to do this by using `list comprehensions`,

```
def modify_biglist(bigl):
    ret =[]
    for alist in bigl:
        alist[2] = ' '.join(alist[2:])
        del alist[3:]
        ret.append(alist)
    return ret
```

This does the job..but it looks a bit convoluted -having  a local variable `ret` and  using `del`? Can someone suggest something better

Comment: Do you want to change the list in place, i.e. modify the list instead of creating a new one?  Your current code does both, modifying the original list *and* returning a new list.

Comment: in place modification would be welcome I guess

Comment: You could achieve this in your original code by simply omitting all lines containing `ret`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
[[x[0], x[1], " ".join(x[2:])] for x in biglist]
```

or, in-place:

```
for x in biglist:
    x[2:] = [" ".join(x[2:])]
```

Answer (score 5):

To modify your list in place, you could use the following simplification of your code:

```
for a in big_list:
    a[2:] = [" ".join(a[2:])]
```

Answer (score 1):

This ought to do it:

```
[x[:2] + [" ".join(x[2:])] for x in biglist]
```

Slightly shorter.